# Cucumber Aruba trying to change directory results in a strange error

Tags: ruby, cucumber, command-line-interface, aruba

So I create the dotfiles directory and then `cd` to dotfiles. However, cucumber aruba is giving me an error that says dotfiles is not a directory. I can't figure out why this is? the code in pry results in the correct behavior.

```
  @creation
  Scenario: Create a dotfiles git repository
    Given the directory dotfiles does not exist in the home directory
    When I successfully run `dotfiles init dotfile_one dotfile_two dotfile_three`
    Then a dotfiles directory should exist in the home directory
    When I change directory to the dotfiles directory ### Fails here ###
    Then a file named ".git" should exist
```

my steps

```
Given /^the directory dotfiles does not exist in the home directory$/ do
  step %(a directory named "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles" should not exist)
end

Then /^a dotfiles directory should exist in the home directory$/ do
  step %(a directory named "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles" should exist)
end

When /^I change directory to the dotfiles directory$/ do
  step %(I cd to "#{ENV['HOME']}/dotfiles")
end
```

before hook:

```
Before('@creation') do
  FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(ENV['HOME'], 'dotfiles'))
end
```

the source

```
module Dotfiles
  class Repository

    def self.init(location, dotfiles)
      # create the dotfiles directory and git init
      FileUtils.chdir(location) do
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
      end
      FileUtils.chdir(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
    end

  end
end
```

Short version of error

```
When I change directory to the dotfiles directory                             # features/step_definitions/aruba_steps.rb:13
      tmp/aruba/Users/Brian/dotfiles is not a directory. (RuntimeError)
```

Here is the error with full trace

```
@creation
  Scenario: Create a dotfiles git repository                                      # features/dotfiles_repository.feature:6
    Given the directory dotfiles does not exist in the home directory             # features/step_definitions/aruba_steps.rb:5
    When I successfully run `dotfiles init dotfile_one dotfile_two dotfile_three` # aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:71
    Then a dotfiles directory should exist in the home directory                  # features/step_definitions/aruba_steps.rb:9
    When I change directory to the dotfiles directory                             # features/step_definitions/aruba_steps.rb:13
      tmp/aruba/Users/Brian/dotfiles is not a directory. (RuntimeError)
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/api.rb:22:in `cd'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_step_definition.rb:97:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:25:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:60:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_world.rb:52:in `step'
      /Users/Brian/gems/dotfiles/features/step_definitions/aruba_steps.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_step_definition.rb:97:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:25:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:60:in `invoke'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:38:in `accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:106:in `block in visit_step'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:105:in `visit_step'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:19:in `block in accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:18:in `each'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:18:in `accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:100:in `block in visit_steps'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:99:in `visit_steps'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:15:in `block in execute'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in with_hooks'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:98:in `before_and_after'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:81:in `block in with_hooks'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `call'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `block (3 levels) in around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:in `block in around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:in `call'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:in `execute_around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in `around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:in `call'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:in `around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:93:in `around'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:80:in `with_hooks'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `execute'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:32:in `block in accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:79:in `with_visitor'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:31:in `accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:58:in `block in visit_feature_element'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:57:in `visit_feature_element'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:38:in `block in accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in `each'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in `accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:27:in `block in visit_feature'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:26:in `visit_feature'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `block in accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:27:in `accept'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:21:in `block in visit_features'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_features'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:48:in `run!'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
      features/dotfiles_repository.feature:10:in `When I change directory to the dotfiles directory'
    Then a file named ".git" should exist                                         # aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:264

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/dotfiles_repository.feature:6 # Scenario: Create a dotfiles git repository

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 3 passed)
0m0.631s
```

Anyone have any solutions or suggestions? Don't hesitate to ask if you have a question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that I would do differently. There's no guarantee that this will make a difference, but it might.

`dotfiles` is never used in your code. `'dotfiles'` is, so why do you require it as a parameter?

```
def self.init(location, dotfiles)
```

Ruby can interpret these lines two ways:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
FileUtils.chdir(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
```

Notice the difference in parenthesis to force parameter assignment in these lines:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(location), 'dotfiles')
FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(location, 'dotfiles'))

FileUtils.chdir(File.join(location), 'dotfiles')
FileUtils.chdir(File.join(location, 'dotfiles'))
```

Instead of writing your code like:

```
def self.init(location, dotfiles)
  # create the dotfiles directory and git init
  FileUtils.chdir(location) do
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
  end
  FileUtils.chdir(File.join location, 'dotfiles')
end
```

I'd write it like this instead:

```
def self.init(location)

  # create the dotfiles directory and git init
  FileUtils.chdir(location) do
    FileUtils.mkdir('dotfiles')
  end

  FileUtils.chdir('dotfiles')

end
```

Although Ruby allows us to not use parenthesis to surround parameters to a method, that is the source of untold many questions asked on Stack Overflow because code won't work. Parenthesis are important to the interpreter, to explicitely tell it what we really mean. When you don't use them, it will follow its normal order of operations and use rules of precendence to try to figure out what section of a line should be processed first, and without the parenthesis to force order of operation, it can make mistakes.

Our choice, at that point, is to either move the operation ahead of where we're going to use its result, or use parenthesis to make it clear what should happen when.

Comment: This is a class method that gets called from a Thor CLI class. the individual `dotfiles` that are passed in from the command `dotfiles init dotfile_one dotfile_two dotfile_three` will be used later in the method, I just haven`t gotten there yet. Sorry for the confusion but there are the files `dotfiles` and the directory `dotfiles`. I can see where that is confusing. I just don't normally refactor before my tests pass.

Comment: Also thanks for the suggestions but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I just ran with a similiar problem. After a long time of investigation this line caught my attention:

```
tmp/aruba/Users/Brian/dotfiles is not a directory. (RuntimeError)
```

See how it begins with 'tmp/aruba'? Needless to say, my problem also had this 'tmp/aruba/' on it. If you look at the [readme at github](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba#use-a-different-working-directory) closely enough you will find out that aruba has a "working directory where it performs its file operations".

When I followed the instructions there I got it working alright!